# My boss found out I used to be on probation and is forcing me to quit and admit to thefts I did not do

Tags: management

One day at work I was talking to a co-worker about my probation, saying that I was off probation and my boss overheard. My boss asked me if I used to be on probation I admitted I used to be but I completed it and have been off since September.

A few days later, he asked to speak with me, saying that money is missing and since I was a new hire I had to repay that money ($75 dollars) in order to receive my paycheck, and also sign a paper that I quit. I told him I didn’t take the money—I swear I didn’t—but he insisted I sign and bring him a money order for $75 and until I sign the paper I can’t get my paycheck.

I didn’t have a choice: my rent and car payment were due and I needed my paycheck. So I brought a money order and signed the paper. I had a final check due and I went on payday with cops standing by to avoid him accusing me of anything else. He still refused to give me my check. The cops even asked him why he was holding my check. Again he stated money been missing and accounts charged that were not supposed to be and he was blaming me. I haven’t been there for two weeks! Can I do something about this? He told me he would win because I have a past police record but I honestly didn't take the money.

Comment: I wonder if the boss is the thief.

Comment: Don't sign anything. Talk to your boss' boss. Get a lawyer. Look for another job.

Comment: How were you able to get cops to come with you to your job to pick up a check? How does one arrange for that to happen?

Comment: You need an attorney, and you should also contact the press.  TV Stations love this sort of thing.

Comment: @JakeGould - It's called a civil assistance call.  Most law enforcement agencies do it, but terms vary greatly by department.

Comment: "He told me he would win because I have a past police record" .. well, the fact that you signed a confession wouldn't help your case, either.

Answer (score 9):

If you explain that you didn't do it to the judge, chances are pretty good that  nothing untoward will happen to you. I don't know what proof your boss has that you stole anything but if all he can say is that money is missing, then he has absolutely has no proof.

If you are accused in court of stealing, the fact that you were on probation cannot be mentioned at trial because it would prejudice the presumption of your innocence - I pretty much know this from having been called as in a prospective juror every two years for twenty years and every four years in the last ten years.

Your boss is a bottom feeder who is attempting to intimidate you and extort from you. I suggest that you pick yourself another place of employment before he pulls a repeat performance - with all the stress that is is implied - on you.